# How do I reverse the order of PriorityQueue in python?

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

I have created a simple priority queue in python that orders items by their value:

```
import Queue
q = Queue.PriorityQueue()
for it in items:
    q.put((it.value, it))
```

but when i print the queue using:

```
while not q.empty()
    print q.get()
```

it will always print the lowest value first. is there a way of getting the last item in a queue without changing the last two lines in the top bit of code to:

```
for it in items:
    q.put((-1*it.value, it))
```

because that seems a bit messy and creates problems if i want to use that information for something else (i would have to multiply it by -1 again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* just make your own class that inherits from PriorityQueue and does the messy -1 multiplication under the hood for you:

```
class ReversePriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):

def put(self, tup):
    newtup = tup[0] * -1, tup[1]
    PriorityQueue.put(self, newtup)

def get(self):
    tup = PriorityQueue.get(self)
    newtup = tup[0] * -1, tup[1]
    return newtup
```

This appears to work with tuples, at least:

```
Q = ReversePriorityQueue()

In [94]: Q.put((1,1))

In [95]: Q.get()
Out[95]: (1, 1)

In [96]: Q.put((1,1))

In [97]: Q.put((5,5))

In [98]: Q.put((9,9))

In [99]: Q.get()
Out[99]: (9, 9)

In [100]: Q.get()
Out[100]: (5, 5)

In [101]: Q.get()
Out[101]: (1, 1)
```

I'm sure you could generalize the code to work with more than just tuples from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the transformation transparent.

What you want is to have a new `q.get` and a new `q.put` that transparently modifies data in and out of queue to reverse order:

```
# new reversed priority put method
q.oldput = q.put
q.put = lambda p, i: q.oldput((p * -1, i))

# new reversed priority get method
q.oldget = q.get
# create get closure for queue
def newget(q):
    def g():
        item = q.oldget()
        # reverse first element
        return item[0] * -1, item[1]
    # return get method for given queue
    return g
# bind to queue
q.get = newget(q)

# test
items = range(10)
for it in items:
    q.put(*(it, it))

while not q.empty():
    print q.get()
```

If this is to be made to a more robust code I strongly recommend using a class and not just re-bind the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a customized Class instead of a tuple.
Then you can do whatever you like in the cmp.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to avoid multiplying by -1 when putting to the priority queue. You can do something like this.

Make a wrapper class

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def __lt__(self, next):
        return self.value[0] > next.value[0]
```

Notice that I've modified the `__lt__` function, I've used `>` instead of `<` deliberately.

Now for putting an element to the Priority Queue do

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.put(Wrapper((priority, 'extra data')))
```

Now while getting the element make sure to use the `value` attribute instead

```
t = pq.get().value
```

Answer (score -1):

By definition you can only retrieve items from the front of a queue. To reverse the order, you could push everything onto a stack, and then pop items off the stack. Since a stack both adds and retrieves items from its back, this has the same effect as reversing the queue.

Comment: but that would mean pushing everything onto a stack every time i wanted to get something off the back of the queue wouldnt it? that would be very inefficient i would imagine, especially for very large input sizes..

Answer (score -1):

In the case of `Queue.PriorityQueue`

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0]).

So can you try `queue.LifoQueue`.It is of `LIFO` mechanism.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) (assuming python 2.7):

```
The lowest valued entries are retrieved first
```

So that would mean, no, you can't.

Comment: fair enough, i read the spec, but thought there might have been another special method i was missing or something. never mind, i can just multiply by -1 i suppose